# llvm::BranchInst::getSuccessor(unsigned int) assertion failure?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am trying to run the following pass using LLVM opt and I get an assertion failure. My LLVM version is 6.0.0

```
    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {

            for(auto it = F.begin(); it != F.end(); it++){
                BasicBlock& bb = *it;
                auto bi = dyn_cast<BranchInst>(bb.getTerminator()); 
                if(bi && bi->getNumSuccessors() == 2){

                    BasicBlock* dest1 = bi->getSuccessor(0);
                    // do some work with dest1
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
```

Output with opt looks like,

```
opt: /installs/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:299: typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type llvm::cast_or_null(Y*) [with X = llvm::BasicBlock; Y = llvm::Value; typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type = llvm::BasicBlock*]: Assertion `isa<X>(Val) && "cast_or_null<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"' failed.
#0 0x000055b6f6cc4fba (opt+0x11fbfba)
#1 0x000055b6f6cc301e (opt+0x11fa01e)
#2 0x000055b6f6cc316c (opt+0x11fa16c)
#3 0x00007f1fc4186890 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x12890)
#4 0x00007f1fc2e37e97 gsignal (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x3ee97)
#5 0x00007f1fc2e39801 abort (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x40801)
#6 0x00007f1fc2e2939a (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x3039a)
#7 0x00007f1fc2e29412 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x30412)
#8 0x00007f1fc2bf5103 llvm::cast_retty<llvm::BasicBlock, llvm::Value*>::ret_type llvm::cast_or_null<llvm::BasicBlock, llvm::Value>(llvm::Value*) /installs/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:299:0
#9 0x00007f1fc2bf4edf llvm::BranchInst::getSuccessor(unsigned int) const /installs/local/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:3059:0
#10 0x00007f1fc2bf4751 (anonymous namespace)::SkeletonPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) /home/charitha/workspace/rocm/control-flow-opt/lcs/MergePass.cpp:24:0
#11 0x000055b6f67bcf5a (opt+0xcf3f5a)
#12 0x000055b6f67bd003 (opt+0xcf4003)
#13 0x000055b6f67bcb14 (opt+0xcf3b14)
#14 0x000055b6f5e54765 (opt+0x38b765)
#15 0x00007f1fc2e1ab97 __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b97)
#16 0x000055b6f5ea75fa (opt+0x3de5fa)
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: opt -load /workspace/rocm/control-flow-opt/build/lcs/libMergePass.so -skeleton 
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '<stdin>'.
2.  Running pass 'Skeleton pass' on function '@foo'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I comment out the line `BasicBlock* dest1 = bi->getSuccessor(0);` everything works.

Comment: IMO this code should be working. Could you please add a snippet of code(or IR) to reproduce this behavior? 
Overall it feels a bit like a memory-related issue. Can you compile it with sanitizers or run under `valgrind`? What happens if you try printing the branch instruction? Does it crash as well?

Comment: It turned out to be a shared library issue. I compiled my code out of LLVM source initially and had this issue. Then placed my pass inside lib/Transforms and it worked just fine.

Comment: I’m glad that you solved the problem! :-)